# JavaScript - How .appendChild() while looping?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, appendchild

When I click on the button, I only get one "div" in the color green.
But I would like to have 3 "divs" in red, orange and green with only one click. How can I do this? See my code below:

```
<!-- HTML CODE -->
<section id="container"></section>
<button onclick="myFunc()">BUTTON 1</button>


// JavaScript Code
function myFunc()
{
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");

  const colorArray = ["red", "orange", "green"];
  var divArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
      divArray.push(newDiv);
      var temp = divArray[i];
      temp.setAttribute("style", "background-color: "+ colorArray[i]);
      container.appendChild(divArray[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do `document.createElement` inside the loop:

```js
function myFunc() {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  const colorArray = ["red", "orange", "green"];
  var divArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.classList.add("new-div")
    divArray.push(newDiv);
    var temp = divArray[i];
    temp.setAttribute("style", "background-color: " + colorArray[i]);
    container.appendChild(divArray[i]);
  }
}
```

```css
.new-div {
  outline: 1px solid salmon;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section id="container"></section>
<button onclick="myFunc()">BUTTON 1</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, to put the "document.createElement" inside the loop works for me!

Answer (score 3):

You can't reuse a single element, instead you have to create a new one for each step inside the loop. And a `<div>` needs either some size or some content to actually appear.
So the minimal changes could be the 3 lines with comments:

```js
function myFunc()
{
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  //var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); // <-- you can't reuse

  const colorArray = ["red", "orange", "green"];
  var divArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
      var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); // <-- have to create a new one
      newDiv.innerHTML="&nbsp;"; // <-- a completely empty, dimensionless div won't appear
      divArray.push(newDiv);
      var temp = divArray[i];
      temp.setAttribute("style", "background-color: "+ colorArray[i]);
      container.appendChild(divArray[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="container"></section>
<button onclick="myFunc()">BUTTON 1</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have updated your snippet with syntax correction. Since you are adding new elements to be appended, it's better to create the div element within the loop.

```js
function myFunc() {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");

  const colorArray = ["red", "orange", "green"];
  var divArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)

  {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");

    newDiv.textContent = i;
    divArray.push(newDiv);

    newDiv.setAttribute("style", "background-color: " + colorArray[i]);

    container.append(newDiv);
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="container"></section>
<button onclick="myFunc()">BUTTON 1</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would argue thing can be made much simpler:

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container"),
  colorArray = ["red", "orange", "green"];
function myFunc() {
  for (let color of colorArray) {
    container.insertAdjacentHTML(
      "afterend",
      `<div style="background-color:${color};">New div colored ${color}</div>`
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="container"></section>
<button onclick="myFunc()">BUTTON 1</button>
```

Comment: I would have used classes for the style rather than embed it but that is a design choice - I I do see the simplification advantage.  I would see this as likely the best option of those posted given that.